# update text value to database with ajax in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

why it is my code doesn't work? maybe I miss something.

here is my code

View **admin_page.php**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 // Ajax post
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $(".submit").click(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  var message = $("input#l_message").val();

  jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "admin/user_data_submit",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {l_message: message},
   success: function(res) {
  if (res)
  {
   // Show Entered Value
   jQuery("div#msg").show();
    jQuery("div#msg").html(res..message);
  }
  }
  });

 });
 });
 </script>
<body>
<?php echo form_open();
    echo form_label('Librarians Message');?>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="the_librarian" id="l_message"></textarea>
    <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Update',"class='submit'");?>
 <?php echo form_close();?>
</body>
```

in my controller **admin.php**

```
public function user_data_submit()
{
    $data = array('message' => $this->input->post('l_message'),
 );
  $this->home_admin_database->librarian_msg_insert($data);
  //Either you can print value or you can send value to database
  echo json_encode($data);
 }
```

then in my model **Home_admin_database.php**

```
public function librarian_msg_insert($data) {
$message = array(
           'message' => $data,
        );
 // Query to insert data in database
  $this->db->where('lm_id', '1');
  $this->db->update('librarians_message', $message);
  if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
     return true;
    }
   else {
   return false;
   }
  }
```

when I click the update button nothing happen and the page refresh without changing the database. help me please...

I want to update the database without refreshing the page then display a message after the success..

Comment: did you use tinymce for textarea ?

Comment: In ur ajax change "type" to method: "POST"

Comment: Also check your network tab in the browser. Check if there are any errors being displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
 var message = $("input#l_message").val();
```

with

```
var message = $("textarea#l_message").val();
```

Then it should work

Comment: not working sir kumar, I tried to put alert('test') before the jQuery.ajax then make the jQuery.ajax as comment. when I click the button the alert popup shown but if I remove the the jQuery.ajax as comment nothing happen and my page refresh then nothing change to my database...

Comment: @MGBC jQuery("div#msg").html(res..message); to jQuery("div#msg").html(res.message);

Comment: doesn't work sir even I change it. I think there was a problem on the ajax syntax sir, I tried to put alert(); before the jQuery.ajax and remove the jQuery.ajax method., when I click the button the alert popup shown... maybe the ajax is the problem but dont know how to fix it...

Comment: I admit, Im not expert in English language, sorry for that.

Comment: @MGBC YOur ajax is working now just open your console and look for network tab and go to last and look for "user_data_submit" and add a screenshot link of that.

Comment: @MGBC  $this->db->update('librarians_message', $message); to  $this->db->update('librarians_message', $data); --- in Home_admin_database.php

And please reply a bit faster

Comment: I have 3 errors in my control  the 1 is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected the next is Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) and the last 1 is Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102454/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-mgb-c).

Answer (score 0):

in your view file try using

```
echo form_button('submit', 'Update',"class='submit'");
```

instead of

```
echo form_submit('submit', 'Update',"class='submit'");
```

Try your luck with the submit event instead of click if above not working...

Also Replace

```
var message = $("input#l_message").val();
```

with

```
var message = $("#l_message").val();
```

=> Another step is to use

```
<form Method="Post" class="submit_form">
```

instead of

```
echo form_open();
```

or remove form action attribute by jquery on document load

and 
`$(".submit_form").submit(function(event) {...});` for ajax call

Comment: I have done some editing to my answer.. please try... good luck

Comment: i tried but nothing happen even I change it into submit. is there any way to trace the problem like putting an alert?

Comment: try Another step is to use 

    <form Method="Post" class="submit_form">

instead of 

    echo form_open();

or remove form action attribute by jquery

Comment: Sir Raj my javascript does not have any class name "submit_form" is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

Hello i guess you using tinymce, tinymce cannot get value like that you should add
to get value

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
```

then please change your javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 // Ajax post
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $(".submit").click(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();
  tinyMCE.triggerSave();
  var message = $("#l_message").val();

alert(message) //please see is it right value or not !

  jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "admin/user_data_submit",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {l_message: message},
   success: function(res) {
  if (res)
  {
   // Show Entered Value
   jQuery("div#msg").show();
    jQuery("div#msg").html(res..message);
  }
  }
  });

 });
 });
 </script>
```

hope this help someone using tinymce,

Comment: not working sir,, the error is GET http://localhost/nmsc/js/jquery.min.js  is there any problem with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Change your **View** code with this :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(){
          // get all post from form with id form-msg
            dataString = $("#form-msg").serialize(); 
            $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin/user_data_submit", 
            //parsing data to your controller
            data:dataString, 

            success:function (data) {
              // Show Entered Value
            $("div#msg").show();
            $("div#msg").html(data);
                alert('Success');
            }

            });

        return false;
        }); 
    }); 
 </script>

<body>

    <?php  
    // add form id
    echo form_open('',"id='form-msg'"); 
    echo form_label('Librarians Message');?>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="the_librarian" id="l_message"></textarea>    
    <?php 
    // add button
    echo form_button('submit', 'Update',"id='submit'"); 
    ?>
    <?php echo form_close();?>

</body>
```